# modifiying random forest such that all trees have some (predetermined) features in common

Tags: regression, random-forest, feature-selection

I am currently looking at a regression problem that I  am trying to solve using random forest. The data set has approx 200 features.

Two of 200 features are important (known from the business use case), and I would like to make sure they are used in every tree  in random forest. 
Question:  does this makes sense from a theoretical point of view?
And if yes, has anyone done it before?

I would appreciate any thoughts, references, etc.

Thanks.